# Google Drive API Change Ownership oAuth

Tags: java, oauth, permissions, google-drive-realtime-api

I have created an oAuth2 Google Drive application and am creating new files under the developer.gserviceaccount.com service account.  I would like to change ownership to another account in the domain who owns this service account.

I have the file id of the newly created file and the permission id of the user I'd like to transfer ownership to, however when I run:

```
File body;
File file;

body = new File();
body.setTitle(gdf.getTitle());
body.setDescription(gdf.getDescription());            
body.setMimeType(gdf.getMime_type());
body.setUserPermission(p);

// new file gets created ok
file = d.files().insert(body).execute();  

// create new permission for new user account
Permission p = new Permission();
p.setRole("owner");
p.setType("user");
p.setValue("newaccount@something.com");
p.setId(ACCESS_DOMAIN_PERMISSION_ID);  // <-- known value

d.permissions().update(file.getId(), ACCESS_DOMAIN_PERMISSION_ID, p).execute();
```

The statement fails complaining about not being able to find the ACCESS_DOMAIN_PERMISSION_ID.

Any thoughts?

Edit -

Disregard the above - it appears now I can impersonate a user in the domain to accomplish file creation as a non-developer.gserviceaccount.com user:

During the credential build process:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)                
    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)                
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(pk12)
    .setServiceAccountUser(ACCESS_DOMAIN_IMPERSONATE)    
    .build();
```

The issue appears to be a delegation problem which may be solved with granting domain-wide authority to the service account.

[image: domain-wide delegation]

Will get back as to the success/failure of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegating the domain-wide authority to the service account did the trick.  I added the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://docs.google.com/feeds
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
```

Make sure you define these scopes in

```
List<String>
```

when creating the GoogleCredential in your code.

Comment: Can you point out where I can find this Delgate Domain-wide authority page? Are you running a standalone program that uses the API, or are this an app in Google Web Development?

Hade the same issue, but using a program running on a server that sends up this files that need to be changed to another user within the same domain. But cannot modify the parentId correctly since it both ends up in root and the parentId when the ownership is changed.